# First Dropwizard Application Builds But Doesn't Execute

Tags: java, maven, dropwizard

I'm walking through the [intro to Dropwizard](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.1/docs/getting-started.html) on a Windows machine, and I seem to be stuck at the point where I'm supposed to be able to run the application.  Here's what I execute from the command line:

> java -jar target/hello-world-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Instead of usage result the intro says I should receive, I get the following error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.helloworld.HelloWorldApplication

The output of the 'mvn package' command indicates a successful build.  The configured CLASSPATH environment variable includes '.' for the current directory, as well as the 'lib' and 'bin' subfolder of the JDK installation.  JAVA_HOME is correctly configured for the JDK location also.  What am I missing in my pom.xml, environment variables or elsewhere that could result in reported successful Maven build where the resulting jar can't be executed?

Comment: What does the `java` command look like you're using to execute the jar?

Comment: Does `com.example.helloworld.HelloWorldApplication` actually exist as the main class? One thing about that tutorial, is that the main class is specified in the pom file for one of the plugins. You need to change that to _your_ main class, if it is something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably either:

- You forgot to include a `package com.example.helloworld;` statement at the top of your `HelloWorldApplication`
- Your HelloWorldApplication source file is not at the ***exact*** path `${project.basedir}/src/main/java/com/example/helloworld/HelloWorldApplication.java` (make sure to check the `src/main/java` part too)

Comment: The package statement is present in the file, but your source file path suggestion sounds like what I need to fix.

Comment: Well if it ends up not being the path, you could try building and running https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/tree/master/dropwizard-example, and that'll help you figure out if your project or your environment is the problem.

Comment: The path ended up being the issue, as indicated in option 2 of the answer from @heenenee.  In addition, I had to put my pom.xml file at the same level as the 'src' folder.  Once I did that, the target folder created by Maven contained everything it should have (jar files, .class files, etc).  Thanks so much for your help.